# Any other FuseSearch.js examples in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, search

Have been researching about using [FuseSearch](https://github.com/naomap/leaflet-fusesearch) and using this [example](http://dev.cartocite.fr/CultureNantes/).
The only difference is that am using polygons.Its working well but not highlighting polygons on results click.
Has anyone done a similar app with polygons and has integrated the FuseSearch plugin?
Please help!!

Comment: Hi @Wanjohi254 perhaps you can provide a jsfiddle of what you have so far.

Comment: @rowanwins Sorry for late response.I am new to Jsfiddle and got some difficulties using it but have put up something [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wanjohikibui/jrpn6d4L/).You can have a look.

Comment: Hi @Wanjohi254 sorry for the slow reply. I've updated your fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/rowanwins/jrpn6d4L/2/ so that it now loads the map. Could you please add your data url on line 48 as that's the one thing that seems to be missing

Comment: Hello @rowanwins.Very sorry for this late reply.Thanks for the update.I have edited the data section as requested.The Geojson data is stored [Here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/38mol).Thank you